# replace multiple columns of data frame with indexing in r

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, replace, multiple-columns

I'm trying to replace multiple columns of a large data frame based with indexing.  What I want/have done so far combines [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54615462/how-to-replace-certain-values-in-a-specific-rows-and-columns-with-na-in-r) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25768305/r-replace-multiple-values-in-multiple-columns-of-dataframes-with-na). Let me provide the example for clarity.

Here is much simplified sample data in dput format:

```
DF <-
structure(list(Fruits = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L), 
.Label = c("Apples", "Avocado", "Oranges", "Pineapple"), 
class = "factor"), Weight2 = c(20L, 15L, 40L, 60L), 
Weight = c(2L, 4L, 8L, 5L), `Number` = c(10L, 
16L, 6L, 20L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

Fruits   Weight   Weight2   Number

  Apples      20      2          10
  Oranges     15      4          16
  Pineapple   40      8           6
  Avocado     60      5          20
```

What I want to do is for DF, given a list of Fruits, change the columns Weight and Weight2 to N. I'll mention that my DF is actually a list of data frames and my list is a list of lists so indexing is needed. Here is my code so far:

```
fruit.to.change <- c("Apples","Pineapple")  
DF$Weight[which(DF$Fruits == fruit.to.change)] <- "N" #change the first column but I want to change multiple columns.

colID <- grepl("Weight", names(DF))
which(DF$Fruits %in% fruit.to.change[1:length(fruit.to.change)]) #gets the positions matching
```

But not sure how to select and replace the columns in `colID`? I'm sure it's just another level of indexing but can't figure it out. I basically want something like `DF$Weight:Weight2 [which(DF$Fruits %in% fruit.to.change )] <- "N"`
Thanks VERY much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can subset rows using `fruit.to.change` and columns with `colID` and replace where the condition is satisfied to `"N"`.

```
DF[DF$Fruits %in% fruit.to.change,colID] <- "N"
DF
#     Fruits Weight2 Weight Number
#1    Apples       N      N     10
#2   Oranges      15      4     16
#3 Pineapple       N      N      6
#4   Avocado      60      5     20
```

Comment: Very much appreciated!  I didn't even think about using the vector  colID like that.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `dplyr` would be

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
   mutate_at(vars(colID), ~ replace(., Fruits %in% fruit.to.change,  "NA"))
```