# Combining Several columns into 1, but overriding the combined value if X variable = a particular value

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I am a beginner to R. I have 13 variables to combine into 1 variable.

I want to override the combined cell if an unrelated VariableX = a specific string, if so, the corresponding cell of the new variable should = the string.

I tried to do this together with an ifelse statement, but didn't really work:

```
Sectors <- paste0("sector", 1:13)
Combinedsectors <- combinedlocations %>% ifelse (Type.of.org != "Independent 
Artist", 
unite(Sector, Sectors, na.rm=TRUE, remove=TRUE), $Sector="Independent 
Artist")
```

What I've done now is combine the sectors into one variable - is it better to just change that call after combining? If so, what would be the code for that?

This is the code I tried to use after first merging the columns:

```
combinedlocations$Sector = ifelse(combinedlocations$Type.Of.org="Independent 
Artist" & !is.na(combinedlocations$Type.Of.org), "Independent Artist", 
combinedlocations$Sector)
```

It gave me an error:
Error: unexpected '=' in "combinedlocations$Sector =
ifelse(combinedlocations$Type.Of.org="

Comment: If you want to check for equality you need to use a doube equal sign: `==`, so it should be `ifelse(..... == "Independent Artist" ...)`

Comment: thanks!! I figured this out - I used this method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54615462/how-to-replace-certain-values-in-a-specific-rows-and-columns-with-na-in-r