# How to change an NA value in a specific row in R?

Tags: r

I am very new in R and still learning.  My data is the Titanic.csv which has 891 observation and 13 variables. I would like to change the NA value on the 62 observation of PassengerID 62 in column 12 (column_name "Embarked") from NA to "S" and 830 observation to "C".

I found similar postings, but it didn't give me what I need.

[How to replace certain values in a specific rows and columns with NA in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54615462/how-to-replace-certain-values-in-a-specific-rows-and-columns-with-na-in-r)

[How to change NA value in a specific row and column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66857163/how-to-change-na-value-in-a-specific-row-and-column?rq=1)

My assignment is asking to use the below function.

```
boat<-within(boat,Embarked[is.na(Embarked)]<-"your choice here")
```

If I do this

```
boat<-within(boat,Embarked[is.na(Embarked)]<- "S")
```

or "C" in where it says "your choice here" it replaces both observations with either "S" or "C".

Below is the example of the Titanic.csv file.

```
PassengerId Survived Pclass Name              Sex    Age  SibSp Parch Ticket Fare    Cabin  Embarked
1           0        3      Braund, Owen      male   22   1     0      A/5   1717.25        S
2           1        1      Cumings,John      female 38   1     0      PC    9971.28  C85   C
17          0        3      Rice, Eugene      male   2    4     1      382   29.125         Q
18          1        2      Williams,Charles  male   0    0            2443  13             S
60          0        3      Goodwin, William  male   11   5     2      CA 21 46.9           S
61          0        3      Sirayanian, Orsen male   22   0     0      2669  7.2292         C
62          1        1      Icard, Amelie     female 38   0     0      11357 80       B28   NA
63          0        1  Harris, Henry         male   45   1     0      36973 83.475   C83   S
```

My apologies if the sample dataframe is somewhat condensed.

Comment: I'm guessing the text about deleting git branches is included by accident?

Comment: Hi Camille, thanks for editing my dataframe.  No, the text about deleting git branches is not included.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
# df is you data frame, first one is the row e.g 62, second one is column e.g 12
df[62, 12]

# Now assign "S" with the `<-` operator 

df[62, 12] <- "S"

# and check if NA is changed to S
df[62, 12]

#Embarked
#<chr>   
#  1 S  

# Same with 
df[830, 12] <- "C"
```

Comment: Thank you TarJae for your help and speedy reply!  It is working now.

Comment: To expand on this for a new R user, the brackets after a data object indicate where you want to locate things. The first part (before the comma) indexes rows, the second part (after the comma) indexes columns. So `df[62, 12]` is indexing the row and column. So if you want to change everything in a column or row, you could leave one blank (i.e. `df[,12]` calls all rows in column 12, and df[62,] calls all columns in row 12. You could also call multiple specific rows/columns, i.e. `df[c(1,6,12), c(3,5,9)]` would call observations 1, 6, and 9 and columns 3, 5, and 9. Good luck!